Unexpected async let behavior in Swift
In the code below, "ALL tasks completed" is being printed before the 3 tasks are actually complete. How can I make sure to wait until they're all finished before executing the MainActor code?
    Task {
        async let _ = func1()
        async let _ = func2()
        async let _ = func3()
                
        await MainActor.run {
            print("ALL tasks completed")
        }
    }
    
    func func1() async {
        try? await someOtherWork()
        print("func1 complete")

    }

func2 and func3 would be similar to func1.

You would await them. You start the three concurrent tasks, it gets to the MainActor.run statement, and then the three unawaited tasks will be canceled when they fall out of scope. See SE-0317, notably the Implicit async let awaiting discussion, for info about what happens if you neglect to explicitly await an async let.

As an aside, if you want to run three tasks concurrently, if they don’t return any values, one might reach for a task group (or discarding task group) instead. It’s much like async let, insofar as they run concurrently, but arguably lends itself to more natural looking code.

You need to explicitly await the function calls, like so:
Task {
    async let f1: () = func1()
    async let f2: () = func2()
    async let f3: () = func3()

    let _ = await (f1, f2, f3)
        
    print("ALL tasks completed")
}

assuming you want all funcX to run in parallel.
If it's OK to simply run them in sequence, get rid of async let and simply await func1() etc.

I just know this is a duplicate, because I've given this exact answer before. But I'm darned if I can find the duplicate.
